# How can the url be changed in Ionic Core so that the page is not reloaded and the browser back and forward buttons work?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

In Ionic Core (Ionic Framework and JavaScript), replacing the url using `history.replace(null, null, NEWURL)` will replace the url with `NEWURL`, however, using the browser back button followed by the browser forward button causes the root page to be shown instead of the page for which the url was replaced.

How can the url be replaced so that the page (component) is kept in the browser history in its current state, it is not refreshed/recreated, and it can be re-visited using the browser forward and back buttons?